# Using wildcard for custom HTML tags in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, radiant, code-inspection

I'm developing a lot of RadiantCMS applications, and this CMS uses custom radiant tags which are translated to content and html at runtime. So, my HTML templates have a markup like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <r:content />
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

This is all fine, but Rubymine complains about all the `<r:content />` tags being invalid html. The effect is that my html-templates are loaded with error-notifications.

I know that you can customize the Rubymine Inspections, and allow Custom HTML Tags, but there are almost unlimited `<r:... />` tags available. To add all possibilities in the customtags field would be hours of work and not very flexible, because new tags come and go by the month.

What I want to do is pass in a wildcard for the `r:` so that all those tags are allowed as valid html tags. I tried some REGEX options but gave me no results.

Does anyone have experience with Rubymine Inspections and how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature to define inspections per **Scope**. You can add a new Scope for all your project files **except** these template files (they can be excluded either by directory or name pattern). Then in the **Inspection** settings you can add this scope and configure the inspection reporting invalid HTML tags to trigger only in the custom scope, not for all the files. As your templates with `<r:... />` are excluded from this scope, inspection will not report such files.

It's not ideal, as it will not report other possibly invalid tags in the template files, but right now there is no way to ignore tags by pattern, but you can [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: It is an alternative, but I'd rather keep the inspection on. Although messing around gave me some results. For most templates the custom tags are now allowed, but on some others they are not. Not sure what causes this, but if I find out I will report it here.

Comment: This is the best solution for now. I filed a feature request, but I guess it won't go high up on their attention because it's pretty specific.